# ExpandableListActivity onChildClick dosen't work after adding ImageButton

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have **ExpandableListActivity** with custom **CursorTreeAdapter**. Everything worked fine until I added **ImageButton** in ChildView. After addition **onChildClick** stopped working. **OnClick** action for ImageButton works fine. When I remove/hide Image button onChildClick starts to function again. Is there an option to combine these two??

Comment: did you set Focusable false for imagebutton

Comment: I had android:focusable="false" but it didn't work. After setting button.setFocusable(false) programmatically it started working. Strange...

Comment: really its Strange for me also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting focusable option to false **button.setFocusable(false)** did the trick, similar to Samir's suggestion.